# How to get refresh_token from response_code return by grantOfflineAccess

Tags: angular, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am struck on on invalid_grant issue. I refer the gapi doc and implement the flow like as,

```
var authorisationRequestData =
  {
    'client_id': clientId,
    'scope': scopes,
    'immediate': immediate,
    prompt: 'consent',
    access_type: 'offline',
  include_granted_scope: true,
  }

  const authInstance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  authInstance.grantOfflineAccess(authorisationRequestData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
      var all_token = JSON.stringify(gapi.auth.getToken());
      console.log("Token =" + all_token);
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.code);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I get the access token and response_code from above implementation and able to create calendar event against user. But after 1 hour it is giving me error like as, "Error: invalid_grant, code:400".Token return by grantOfflineAccess like as "4/-QA8fj7FyvcPzlVwsapQwyqyKJs0MwkQlNdGhACVgOx3YSP5JamyEplViIx-uSV3JeAHrp9n0RZC0FMSX7IwAQk"

Answer (score 1):

As [Nirav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828033/5924089) mentioned, you need to exchange this one-time token for a refresh token that you can use anytime.

You should use [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#readme) to complete this workflow in a Node.js back-end. For this, you'll use the authentication code to get a refresh token. However, as this is an offline workflow, you also need to verify the integrity of the provided code as the [documentation explains](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth):

```js
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

/**
* Create a new OAuth2Client, and go through the OAuth2 content
* workflow. Return the refresh token.
*/
function getRefreshToken(code, scope) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create an oAuth client to authorize the API call. Secrets should be 
    // downloaded from the Google Developers Console.
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
      YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
      YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
      YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
    );

    // Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
    const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope,
    });
    
    // Verify the integrity of the idToken through the authentication 
    // code and use the user information contained in the token
    const { tokens } = await client.getToken(code);
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: tokens.id_token!,
      audience: keys.web.client_secret,
    });
    idInfo = ticket.getPayload();
    return tokens.refresh_token;
  })
}
```

With this refresh token, you can create a Google API's client with the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#readme) library anytime. I'm also using this workflow to create events. For a complete workflow with a Node.js back-end, you might find [my gist](https://gist.github.com/flandrade/a943a47e3575fb8805499e18e6b23c07) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are getting from response is one-time code that your server should exchange for `Access Token` and `Refresh Token`. Please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_6_send_the_authorization_code_to_the_server).

It is not the best practice to store refresh_token on client app as it is not secured. If you just have client app, I would recommend to follow [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the link, Do you have any sample for the same? I am continously getting "Bad request as error and error message is Invalid_grant"

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you using Hybrid flow?

Comment: code shared in question, you have any sample for the same?

Comment: How to exchange one-time code with google for getting access_token and refresh_token?

Comment: I don't have sample. However if you can make repository, I can contribute in that. You need to send one_time code to google with your credential to get access_token and/or refresh_token.
Please refer to [Libraries for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/)